springboot csrf cookie cannot be found in react
I have tried apply crsf protection to my springboot application, which i have successfully call the csrf token through postman with valid response.But when i integrate with react, i just found that i cannot call the post request as expected in react and it just return with the default login html page in springboot. And one issue i found is that i can not get "XSRF-Token" cookie in react which i found in the postman. So i am also wondering should i use the token value in the response or that in cookie , since they are not the same.
Here is the sample response of the api for getting the csrf token:
{
    "token": "WYLRFWBdknUKP5VMM6E9BVpi3S0xqm6EAw5wSzcl1Q5-0-LOaObjJVA58UcnWqB_VowJYTlS8ExUnVqpNzYVeFQctmga49Ct",
    "parameterName": "_csrf",
    "headerName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
}

response in calling login api in frontend:
TypeError: Cannot create property 'token' on string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-oOE/3m0LUMPub4kaC09mrdEhIc+e3exm4xOGxAmuFXhBNF4hcg/6MiAXAf5p0P56" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login with OAuth 2.0</h2><table class="table table-striped">
 <tr><td><a href="/oauth2/authorization/facebook">Facebook</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="/oauth2/authorization/google">Google</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body></html>'


My security chain in spring security:
 return http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler())
                )
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(customAuthFilter, OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)
  .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                   
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults())
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).httpBasic(withDefaults())

                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())
                                )
                                .successHandler(customOAuth2SuccessHandler)
                )

//                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)

                        .
                build();


SpaCsrfTokenRequstHandler:

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRequestHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
    private final CsrfTokenRequestHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Supplier<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
        /*
         * Always use XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to provide BREACH protection of
         * the CsrfToken when it is rendered in the response body.
         */
        this.delegate.handle(request, response, csrfToken);
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveCsrfTokenValue(HttpServletRequest request, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        /*
         * If the request contains a request header, use CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler
         * to resolve the CsrfToken. This applies when a single-page application includes
         * the header value automatically, which was obtained via a cookie containing the
         * raw CsrfToken.
         */
        if (StringUtils.hasText(request.getHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName()))) {
            return super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
        }
        /*
         * In all other cases (e.g. if the request contains a request parameter), use
         * XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to resolve the CsrfToken. This applies
         * when a server-side rendered form includes the _csrf request parameter as a
         * hidden input.
         */
        return this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
    }
}

csrfFIlter:
package com.Acerise.System_api.Config.Security;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
        csrfToken.getToken();

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}



my frontend request:
export async function apiHandler(apiRequest: ApiRequest) {
    var headers: any;
    console.log(getJwt())

    //get crsf token

    if (apiRequest.requireAuth === false) {
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    } else {
        if (getJwt == null) {
            console.log("not authorized for the request")
            return null;
        } else {
            headers = {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${getJwt()}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",


            }
        }
    }
    if (apiRequest.method === "POST") {
        const res = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT + "/auth/crsf")

        const csrfToken = res.data.token
        console.log(csrfToken)

        headers["xsrf-token"] = csrfToken

    }
    console.log(API_ENDPOINT + apiRequest.uri);
    console.log(headers)
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            url: API_ENDPOINT + apiRequest.uri,
            method: apiRequest.method,
            data: apiRequest.body,
            headers: headers,
            // withCredentials: true

        })
        console.log(response.status)

        return response;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log("error: ", error.response.data)
        if (error.response.status == 401) {
            console.log("try refreshing token")
            const res = await _refreshToken();
            if (res) {
                window.location.reload();
            }


        }

        else {
            toast.error(error.response.data.message)
        }


        // store.dispatch(Unauthenticate())

        return error.response;
    }


}

i have also try changing getting the token from the cookie like changing the above to  :
f (apiRequest.method === "POST") {
        const res = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT + "/auth/crsf")

        const csrfToken = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
        console.log(csrfToken)

        headers["xsrf-token"] = csrfToken

    }

but the result is the same which the csrf token is undefined in console log
Everythings work fine if i just disable crsf protection. And the filter is reference from
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html
The calling of crsf is also work as expected , so the problem should on how to get the token and integrate to my react application.Any help or hints will be thankfully accepted.
